# bootstrap 4: list-inline items for different breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

how can I align list items on top of each other for a breakpoint <=575px (xs), and align the items next to each other for a breakpoint >575px (sm) with bootstrap display properties?

According to [How to display a list inline using Twitter's Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906341/how-to-display-a-list-inline-using-twitters-bootstrap?rq=1) I can use 'list-inline'. Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Phasellus iaculis</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Nulla volutpat</li>
</ul>
```

This does work in general, but how does that work with respect to breakpoints? Usually, bootstrap allows to set the breakpoint in the notation, e.g. 'd-sm-block' (visible only on min-width: 576px), but the documentation doesn't say anything about 'list-inline' in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap does not currently support `list-inline` as of v4.3 - it is merely a utility function across all breakpoints. I also do not see any signs of this being supported in future versions as the [shiplist v4.4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29096) in Github and onward has no references to this.

In order to get what you're looking for using only Bootstrap utilities, you would have to use the `Display` utility class `d-{breakpoint}-inline-flex`. The `ml-{breakpoint}-{size}` `Spacing` utility class can also be used for spacing purposes to continue supporting breakpoint behavioral adjustments.

Open the snippet below in *Full Page* or *Expand snippet* mode to see the result:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="list-unstyled d-sm-inline-flex">
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="ml-sm-3">Phasellus iaculis</li>
  <li class="ml-sm-3">Nulla volutpat</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @tealowpillow does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

As [explained in the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/) the Display classes work for any type of CSS `display:` value. There form `d-sm-inline` or `d-sm-inline-block` will also work.

Comment: how is that related to 'list-inline' (which I was asking about)?